# Запрос курсором SQLite Android

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

Создаю БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Делаю запрос:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper pizzaDB = new PizzaTimeDatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = pizzaDB.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("PTIME",
                new String[]{"TYPE", "TYPE_BONUS", "ORDER_QUANTITY"},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            test1 = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            test3 = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
```

В test3 почему то передается "0", хотя должен быть "1"

Answer (score 2):

Подсказали в другом месте :-)
У мня был лишний вызов перехода на следующую "строку":

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```

Все оказалось слишком просто